# Update: SAM3X problems with systick handler and accessing systick value for microsecond resolution

Tags: c, gcc, arm, compiler-optimization

I am currently struggling with a very simple piece of code which indicate that the level 1 optimizer of ARM GCC damages a simple formula somehow.
This runs on latest Atmel 6.2 Studio using standard compiler settings (O1).
*Atmel Toolchain\ARM GCC\Native\4.8.1426\arm-gnu-toolchain*

The code is quite minimal:

```
volatile uint32_t g_timing_tick_ms=0;
void SysTick_Handler(void)
{
    g_timing_tick_ms++;
}
inline uint32_t get_millis()
{
    return g_timing_tick_ms;
}

uint32_t get_micros()
{
    return  (g_timing_tick_ms * 1000 + (1000 - SysTick->VAL/84));
}

uint8_t timer_expired(timer_ *t)
{
    uint32_t cur_us = get_micros(); 

    uint32_t dt = cur_us - t->last_systick_us;

    t->last_systick_us = cur_us;
    if (t->elapsed <= dt)
    {
// <--------- dt is regularly a huge value (around 0xfffffe00)
// this happens because t->last_systick_us sometimes is bigger than cur_us (overflow)
// however get_micros() is without such an error, cur_us ALWAYS increases and the    
// variables are not modified outside this function which is called every 500us.
        t->elapsed = t->interval;
        return 1;
    }
    t->elapsed -= dt;
    return 0;
};
```

`get_millis` returns the milliseconds from the Systick timer which calls once per millisecond.
The systick timer is 24bit and counts down at a rate of 84mhz.
`get_micros`() uses this systick value and calculates the microseconds passed since last reset and then adds the milliseconds*1000.
This works quite well, I could not find a faster way to get the current microseconds as a timestamp.

The third function shows a sporadic problem, from time to time the value stored in t->last_systick_us (which comes directly from get_micros() is larger than it should be.
To be exact, the last three decimal values are always 986 (20065986,1000986).
The value is around 1000us too high, always with the 986 at the end of the decimal number.
This happens every some calls.

Solutions:
1) Changing:

```
uint32_t dt = cur_us - t->last_systick_us; ---> 
volatile uint32_t dt = cur_us - t->last_systick_us;
```

Changing this variable to volatile solves the issue, which leads to the idea that the compiler is fucking with it in a bad way.
The variable is not static, it's a local one and NOTHING is modifing it from the outside, volatile is a waste but solves the math issues.
2) Changing

uint32_t get_micros() ----->
inline  uint32_t get_micros()
This also solves the issue, however that's not a good fix either as the compiler does not have to put it inline. So this can backfire at some point in the future.

3)
Adding any debug writes or similar into the timer function before the values get changed also fixes it, depending on the code.

It seems to be a bug in the gcc-ARM core compiler, the optimizer somehow ruins the math.
I can supply asm, I don't know the ARM ASM but I noted it removed a "sub" at a part close to the get_micro() formula.
I don't think I have a code error here, it's too simple (and works too well).
Also the solutions show that it's not a coding error, adding or removing inline from the function should not make any difference except optimizations.

Maybe someone knows what to do, experienced/solved similar behaviour.
I am at the edge of completely removing the optimizer but that would likely cost quite a lot of performance.

**Update**

I was just about to prepare the asm differences (and read through it) when I realized the possible reason and I think that's the case.

I think this is a race condition, the interrupt of Systick did not fire yet but the systick timer overflows.
The result is an error of around 1000us (a bit smaller as the timer ticks every 84ns.
That would cause exactly me error, unpredictable and by changing the code the cycles change by changing the cycles it might align the code in a way which causes the race condition to appear later.

I debugged and could verify the problem happens short after a Systick reload.

Sorry for making a too fast guess in a compiler error.

Comment: Why don't you post the disassembly of your functions? That would make things a lot easier for many including myself.

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE: Thanks for your response.
I think I have to take two steps back :/
I update my question, the fault seems to be on my end.

Comment: I tried to help people by keeping the question detailed and I receive minus votings for it. I guess the best is to remove the question and connected solutions ?

Comment: I know the question is older, but I had a similar frustrating experience with SAM3N systick.  The question and your answer were useful.  Please don't delete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is due to a race condition, the compiler is not at a fault.
I am not entirely sure but I think this is a weakness in the SAM3x8e ARM imlementation (or in general Cortex M3) or they did not think about people using the IRQ and the Systick value.

Whatever fix or code I tried I always had one of the two cases:
Interrupt fired during get_micros() calculation
Systick overflowed during get_micros() but no interrupt fired.

get_micros() reads an old millisecond/Systick value and a new systick/millisecond variable, resulting in nearly 1ms error.

One might think adding NVIC_DisableIRQ(SysTick_IRQn); to the start helps.
It does not, it's undocumented in the ASF but NVIC does not handle Systick enable/disable, the IRQn is negative and will not have any effect on the exceptions.
Funny is that NVIC is used to set the priority inside of Atmels driver code likely also without effect.
Another funny aspect is that atmel uses exactly that call in some of its own source code examples.. (well not so funny after 6 hours of time wasted)

I tried guarding the code with __disable_irq() without a positive effect, the same race condition occured (timer is changed but the Systick value has not run over yet)

I tried this:

```
if (SysTick->CTRL & SysTick_CTRL_COUNTFLAG_Msk) micro_us+=1000;
```

This reads the systick control register and checks if the counter was overflown since the last read.
It is supposed to do that according to the atmel sam3x8ek datasheet.
However, the two undocumented sideeffects of READING this register:
1) It starts another Systick interrupt !
2) It resets the countflag value to 0
Not a single word about both actions in the datasheet, 2) is useless but wouldn't be an issue 1) is a showstopper.

The only way  to disable the IRQ is in the system handler, SCB->SHCSR.
However, that would cause a crash if it occurs (hard fault).

Possible solution: disable the clock of the systick, wait for pending IRQs to happen and then continue. That will make sure the read value and the read interrupt are in sync and it will introduce a small timing error and cost additional time in the function itself.

After around 4-5 hours of debugging and fighting with buggy or undocumented features, the best solution I came up with is the following code:

```
  uint32_t get_micros()
{
    //__disable_irq(); // does not affect systick
    static uint32_t last_value;
    volatile uint32_t timestamp = g_timing_tick_ms; // set to volatile to make sure the compiler does not optimize here
    volatile uint32_t val = SysTick->VAL;

    uint32_t micro_us = (timestamp * 1000 + (1000 - val/84));
    if (last_value > micro_us) micro_us+=1000; // Hack: race condition only causes a 1ms delay, this solves it
    last_value = micro_us;
    //if (SysTick->VAL > val ) micro_us+=1000; // undocmented, causes VAL reset to 0
    //if (NVIC_GetPendingIRQ(SysTick_IRQn)) micro_us+=1000; // asf undocumented, does not handle systick (system handler)
    //if (SysTick->CTRL & SysTick_CTRL_COUNTFLAG_Msk) micro_us+=1000;   // triggerd undocumented systick interrupt 


    return  micro_us; // hardcoded auf 84mhz
}
```

I hope this saves someone the time I had to spend.
It introduces a new variable and keeps a running copy of the last value, if time starts to flow backward it adds one ms to the value (the error is always 1ms).

If this does not seem clean enough:
The only lean solution I can think about is to stop the Sysclock and use a Timer instead.
The Timers are better documented (at least for basic use) and they work reliable.
The SAM3 comes with 9 timers.

Comment: Resetting behavior of SysTick Control and Status register COUNTFLAG bit is documented perfectly:


1. Here: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dai0179b/ar01s02s08.html

2. There: https://web.eecs.umich.edu/~prabal/teaching/eecs373-f10/readings/ARMv7-M_ARM.pdf (B3.3.1, also Table B3-25)

3. It's marked as read-only, read-only bits usually reset after reading

Answer (score 2):

You only have to check that `g_timing_tick_ms` did not change during calculation:

```
uint32_t get_micros()
{   
    uint32_t before_ms, after_ms, calc_micros;
    do {
          before_ms = g_timing_tick_ms;
          calc_micros = before_ms * 1000 + (1000 - SysTick->VAL/84);
          after_ms = g_timing_tick_ms;
    } while (before_ms != after_ms);

    return  calc_micros;
}
```

Comment: That won't work.
What if Systick->VAL just overrun but the interrupt did not fire yet ?  I had plenty of these cases and observed them in the debugger.
In this case the micro value will be 1ms lower and before/after will stay the same.

Comment: The code won't work in interrupt context unless Systick priority is lower. The Systick handler must be able to run, and will run as soon as VAL underflows.  Most debuggers swallow exceptions like systick when single-stepping, so using a debugger here can be misleading.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem problem on an STM32F1 (Cortex M3) project and came up with the following:

```
volatile uint32_t time_ovf = 0;

void SysTick_Handler(void)
{
    time_ovf += 1000;
}

uint32_t micros(void)
{
    __disable_irq();    // asm("cpsid i");

    uint32_t m = time_ovf;
    uint32_t t = SysTick->VAL;      // TODO: assume HCLK = 72 MHz

    // Check pending overflow IRQ after we disabled interrupts
    uint32_t o = SCB->ICSR & SCB_ICSR_PENDSTSET_Msk;

    // If overflow and counter rolled over, add 1000 to the microseconds count
    if (o && t > 36000) m+= 1000;

    __enable_irq();     // asm("cpsie i");

    // Systick counts downwards, so subtract it from 999.
    return (m + (999 - t / 72));
}
```

The SysTick timer is configured with a LOAD value = 71999 and its clocked at 72 MHz, so it overflows every milliseconds (just like yours). The idea is to take a snapshot of the overflow count (time_ovf) and the SysTick count (SysTick->VAL) with interrupts disables, then check if an overflow happened between the two and add 1000 to the calculation if so by looking at the PENDSTSET bit of SCB->ICSR.

This gives a monotonically increasing timestamp that overflows naturally at 2^32, so add/subtract arithmetics work nicely with it.

I know this is from 2014, but I hope it helps someone who stumbles upon the same thing...